# Minimizing Frobenius norm involving inverse

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I am looking for methods to solve the following minimization. Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $C\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $E\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$, where $n>m>k$. Additionally, $C$ is positive definite.
$$G(d)=||A-B(C+\text{diag}(d))^{-1}E||^2_F$$
Is there any hopes of finding the positive minimizer (is there just 1?) $d\geq0$ of $G$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\g{\gamma}
\def\t{\times}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Let's use a variable naming convention wherein an upper/lower letter
denotes a matrix/vector and a Greek letter denotes a scalar. Under this scheme, the only variable that needs to be renamed is $\,G\to\g$.

Also, to avoid confusion with differential operations, let's rename $d\to x.$

To enforce positivity, construct $x$ from an *unconstrained* vector $w$
$$\eqalign{
x &= \exp(w) \qiq x \ge 0  \\
dx &= x\odot dw \\
}$$
where $\exp(w)$ is applied elementwise and $\odot$ denotes the elementwise product.

For typing convenience, define the auxiliary variables
$$\eqalign{
X &= \Diag x &\qiq dX = \Diag{dx} \\
  & &\qiq dx = X\,dw \\
F &= \LR{C+X}^{-\o} &\qiq dF = -F\,dX\,F \\
M &= \LR{BFE-A} &\qiq dM = B\:dF\,E \\
}$$
and the Frobenius $(:)$ product
$$\eqalign{
Z,Y&\in\R{m\t n},\quad P\in\R{m\t p},\quad Q\in\R{p\t n} \\
Z:Y &= \trace{Z^TY} \\
Y:Y &= \frob{Y}^2  \\
Z:Y &= Y:Z \;=\; Y^T:Z^T \\
\LR{PQ}:Y &= P:\LR{YQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TY} \\
\\
}$$

---

Write the objective function using the above notation
and calculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
\g &= \tfrac12\LR{M:M}  \\
d\g &= M:dM \\
 &= M:\LR{B\:dF\,E} \\
 &= \LR{B^TME^T}:dF \\
 &= \LR{B^TME^T}:\LR{-F\,dX\,F} \\
 &= -\LR{F^TB^TME^TF^T}:\Diag{X\,dw} \\
 &= -X\diag{F^TB^TME^TF^T}:dw \\
\grad{\g}w &= -X\diag{F^TB^TME^TF^T} \;\doteq\; g(w) \\
}$$
Theoretically, you can set $g(w)=0$ and solve for the optimal $w$ vector, but the expression is sufficiently complicated that it's unlikely that an **analytic** solution can be found.

However, you can use a [gradient descent algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barzilai-Borwein_method)
$$\eqalign{
g_k &= g(w_k) \\
w_{k+\o} &= w_k - \alpha_k\,g_k \\
k &= k + \o \\
}$$
to find a **numerical** solution for $w$, then calculate $\;x=\exp(w)$

### Update

If gradient descent converges too slowly, you can calculate the Hessian and use Newton's method.

Define the variables (using the fact that $F^T=F$)
$$\eqalign{
\def\h{\odot}
\def\Y{Y^\delta}
Y &= \LR{FB^TME^TF} \\
y &= \diag Y \\
\Y &= \Diag y \;\equiv\; \LR{I_m\odot Y} \,\ne\, Y \\
}$$
Use the identity
$$ \diag{B\,\Diag{x}\,R} \;\equiv\; \LR{R^T\h B}x  $$
to obtain
$$\small\eqalign{
dY &= \c{dF}B^TME^TF^T + FB^T\c{dM}E^TF + FB^TME^T\c{dF} \\
 &= -\CLR{F\,dX\,F}B^TME^TF
  - FB^T\CLR{BF\,dX\,FE}E^TF
  - FB^TME^T\CLR{F\,dX\,F} \\
dy &= \diag{dY} \\
 &= -\LR{FEM^TBF\h F}dx
  - \LR{FEE^TF\h FB^TBF}dx  
  - \LR{F\h FB^TME^TF}dx  \\
}$$
and use this to calculate the Hessian
$$\small\eqalign{
g &= -Xy \;\equiv\; -\Y x \\
dg &= -X\,dy \;-\; \Y\,dx \\
 &= +X\LR{F\h FEM^TBF + FEE^TF\h FB^TBF +F\h FB^TME^TF}dx -\Y\,dx \\
&= X\LR{F\h FEM^TBF+FEE^TF\h FB^TBF +F\h FB^TME^TF}X\,dw-\Y X\,dw \\
\grad gw
 &= X\BR{ F\h\LR{Y^T+Y} \:+\: \LR{FEE^TF}\h\LR{FB^TBF} }X - \Y X
 \;\doteq\; H(w) \\
}$$
The Newton iteration converges rapidly (quadratically)
$$\eqalign{
g_k &= g(w_k) \\
H_k &= H(w_k) \\
w_{k+\o} &= w_k - H_k^{-\o} g_k \\
k &= k + \o \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Do you see ways to find the positive minimizer, i.e. $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: @dff Sorry, I missed that requirement. The post has been updated.

Comment: @dff I just noticed that I had missed the negative sign in my Hessian calculation, so I updated the post again.  And upon reflection, I should have chosen something simpler than the exponential function to construct $x,\,$ e.g. 
 $$x = \tfrac12\,(w\odot w) \;\implies\; dx = w\odot dw$$ It works out nearly the same, except that the gradient/Hessian have leading/trailing factors of $U$ instead of $X.\;$

Comment: Thanks for having another look; indeed when experimenting I had very slow convergence of gradient descent. In your comment you refer to $U$, but I don't see it defined anywhere?

Comment: Oops! I meant $w,\;$ the unconstrained variable used to construct $x$.

Comment: $\text{diag}(w)$?

Comment: Yes, the diagonal matrix formed from the unconstrained vector. In my post I am using the uppercase `Diag()` to create a diagonal matrix from a vector argument $W=\operatorname{Diag}(w)$ and the lowercase `diag()`function to create a vector from a matrix argument, i.e.  $w=\operatorname{diag}(W)$